# Syscc and syserrortext in sas

Tags: sas

I am trying to use the automatic macro variables in SAS for error handling, I found that `&syscc` will be 0 when an `%include` statement fails due to a nonexistent file. If I am relying on `&syserrortext` to capture this error message, I can cannot reset the `&syserrortext` within the same session.

Now I have `&syscc` that won't capture errors, `&syserrortext` that captures but cannot be reset, is there an alternate way to handle this?

Answer (score 3):

Per the [documentation of &SYSCC](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/mcrolref/p11nt7mv7k9hl4n1x9zwkralgq1b.htm):

> Note: When the ERRORCHECK= SAS system option is set at NORMAL, the value of SYSCC will be 0 even if an error exists in a LIBNAME or FILENAME statement, or in a LOCK statement in SAS/SHARE software. The value of SYSCC will also be 0 when the %INCLUDE statement fails due to a nonexistent file. For more information, see the [ERRORCHECK= System Option](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lesysoptsref/n074sx2hkq8dzpn1ptoydcmzfspt.htm) in SAS System Options: Reference.

That reference page includes:

> STRICT
>
> > specifies to place the SAS program into syntax-check mode when an error occurs in a LIBNAME or FILENAME statement, or in a LOCK statement in SAS/SHARE software. If the ERRORABEND system option is set and an error occurs in either a LIBNAME or FILENAME statement, SAS terminates. In addition, SAS terminates when a %INCLUDE statement fails due to a non-existent file.

See this example code:

```
%macro errvars;
 %put &=syscc;
 %put &=sysrc;
 %put &=syserrortext;
%mend errvars;

%errvars;
%include "c:\doesnotexist.txt";
%errvars;
* Shows SYSCC=0;
options errorcheck=strict;
%include "c:\doesnotexist.txt";
%errvars;
* Shows SYSCC=1012;
```

Log:

```
 75         %errvars;
 SYSCC=0
 SYSRC=0
 SYSERRORTEXT=
 76         %include "c:\doesnotexist.txt";
 WARNING: Physical file does not exist, c:\doesnotexist.txt.
 ERROR: Cannot open %INCLUDE file c:\doesnotexist.txt.
 77         %errvars;
 SYSCC=0
 SYSRC=0
 SYSERRORTEXT=Cannot open %INCLUDE file c:\doesnotexist.txt.
 78         * Shows SYSCC=0;
 79         options errorcheck=strict;
 80         %include "c:\doesnotexist.txt";
 WARNING: Physical file does not exist, c:\doesnotexist.txt.
 ERROR: Cannot open %INCLUDE file c:\doesnotexist.txt.
 81         %errvars;
 SYSCC=1012
 SYSRC=0
 SYSERRORTEXT=Cannot open %INCLUDE file c:\doesnotexist.txt.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps us greatly